# Using variables as function arguments in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, quotes

I have a simple question about using variables as inputs to a command in a Bash script. I would like to write a script that automatically copies certain contents of a directory, `foo`, to an embedded computer connected over `ssh` in another directory, `bar`.

In other words, I want to turn the following command into an easier to maintain script:

```
ssh -r /foo/{file1,file2,dir1,*.h,*.hpp,*.c,*.cpp} uname@1.1.1.1:~/bar
```

So far, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE='/foo';
FILES='{file1,file2,dir1,*.h,*.hpp,*.c,*.cpp}';
DESTINATION='uname@1.1.1.1:~/bar';

set -x
scp -r $SOURCE/$FILES  $DESTINATION
set +x
```

However, this gets executed as:

```
ssh -r '/foo/{file1,file2,dir1,*.h,*.hpp,*.c,*.cpp}' 'uname@1.1.1.1:~/bar'
```

I'm sure I am using the wrong kinds of quotes or parenthesis somewhere, but I feel like I've tried everything. Thanks to anyone who can help a newbie out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) would tell you that *Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions ...*

I don't think that you have any option but to use `eval` here if you want to make use of *variables* in the command:

```
SOURCE='/foo';
FILES='{file1,file2,dir1,*.h,*.hpp,*.c,*.cpp}';
FILELIST="$(eval echo "${SOURCE}"/"${FILES}")"
```

and later say:

```
scp -r "$FILELIST"  $DESTINATION
```

Comment: Well you certainly got me closer to a solution. With your approach the FILELIST got expanded, but the arguments to scp were still appearing inside single quotes so in my case (where `/foo` is  the current directory `.`, and `DESTINATION` is referencing the home directory, `~`, those symbols weren't getting parsed.  I had to modify your solution to read `scp -r $(eval echo "$FILELIST") $(eval echo $DESTINATION)` to work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you put the braces or the *s inside quotes they will not be expanded by the shell.  So, use:

```
scp -r "$SOURCE/"{file1,file2,dir1,*.h,*.hpp,*.c,*.cpp}  $DESTINATION
```

If you really want to define the file list before calling `scp`, then use a bash array:

```
filelist=( "$SOURCE/"{file1,file2,dir1,*.h,*.hpp,*.c,*.cpp} )

scp -r "${filelist[@]}" $DESTINATION
```

Here, `filelist` is an array and `"${filelist[@]}"` is bash's special incantation to return each filename in the list as a separate argument to `scp`.

Comment: I ended up using something closer to devnull's approach, but thanks for your help and teaching me something new about bash arrays! =)